# Is this defining a new class or new instance?

Tags: java

New to java. Unclear about this piece of code:

```
ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("GameScore");
query.getInBackground("xWMyZ4YEGZ", new GetCallback() {
  public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      // object will be your game score
    } else {
      // something went wrong
    }
  }
});
```

With `new GetCallback() {....}`, is it instancing an instance of GetCallback class or defining a subclass of Getcallback class or both?

Is this Java's way of doing anonymous functions in C/Objective-C and Ruby's blocks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's doing both. It's declaring an anonymous inner class (you'll see a corresponding .class file in the compiled output) and creating a new instance of it.

Java doesn't have a way of creating *just* an anonymous function (as of Java 7) - this is as close as it gets though.

Answer (score 1):

It's anonymous classes, actually it's both creating a class and an instance. Some details [here](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~tmh/courses/allJava/Anonymous.html).

Comment: There is only *one* such anonymous class, but possibly many instances of said class. (The wording makes it sound like the expression does both each time it is evaluated, which is not true.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you're doing:

- You're declaring an *anonymous* inner class
- You're instantiating it
- Finally you're *overriding* the `public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e)` method and providing your own definition of that.

The advantage of having such an anonymous inner class has to do with its usefulness when you want to use an instance of an object which certain tweaks to the actual functionality of the class such as *overloaded methods* (*as in your case*), without having to actually subclass a class.